# How to sort a sparse vector fastest

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have an integer vector. The size of the vector is around 2k, and each number in the vector is in the range of [0, 2M] and there is a high possibility to be 0.

Since it is a sparse vector, I'm wondering if there is a better algorithm than the regular ones to sort the vector? Which sorting algorithm would be the best for this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: Partition it first, to divide the zeros from the non-zeros. Then sort the rest. Oh, and before worrying about that, profile first!

Comment: data representation should accomadate the fact -- store only non-zero values and indices

Comment: That would make lookup of a value by its index more complicate though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a vector of 2000 elements, do not worry too much on how to sort it... it is very small!

That said, if you have a vector with n integers, each of them between 0 and M, and M is small, you can sort it in O(n) time using [Counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

If the vector has n real numbers in some known range, and the numbers are uniformly distributed, you can use [Bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) to sort them in O(n) expected time.

Comment: Thanks for your instant reply! I agree with your point. But I am still curious if there is any way to take the advantage of the sparse characteristic? Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "sparse"? Do you mean that 0 values are not stored in the vector?

Comment: Yes, all 0 values are stored in the vector. I understand this may not be a good data structure to store a vector like this, but it can not be changed or improved in my set-up.

Comment: In this case, Counting sort will be very usefull. Or, as others have said, first move the zeros to the beginning of the vector and sort the rest of the vector.

Answer (score 3):

This answer might be a bit too obvious...

Since most entries are zero why not do a preliminary exchange so that all the zeros are at one
end of the vector and the non-zero elements at the other.

Start from both ends of the
vector. From one end search for the first non-zero element, from the other end search for the
first zero element. Swap them and then continue until the two search positions meet. The vector is now partitioned into two parts at the meeting point. One part contains only zero elements and the other non-zero elements.  Sort the vector from the meeting point over the non-zero elements. There should be very few items that acutally need sorting.

When sorting a few dozen elements or so the actual sorting algorithm used doesn't make much difference from a performance point of view (for a half dozen elements or so, bubble sort is hard to beat!).

Answer (score 1):

You're describing a regular *dense* vector that happens to have lots of `0` elements. A *sparse* vector only stores the nonzero elements, and if an element is not stored then it is assumed to be `0`.

To sort a sparse vector just sort it normally. 2000 is already small, but if you genuinely use a sparse structure and "there is a high possibility [an element is] 0" then that number will be much smaller.

An example of a sparse structure is `vector< pair<int, double> >` where `pair.first` is the index and `pair.second` is the value.

Comment: a little ambiguous, but the original definition of vector sparsity is as he describes. Most good sparse vector *implementations* use the method you describe to save space and perhaps execution time

Answer (score 1):

The best which comes to my mind is Radix Sort, but thats harder to implement than 3-way quicksort. 3-way quicksort is optimal because it will skip a lot of the same elements, being O(n*log(n)) -> O(n), + i think there is an implementation in almost every programming language.